# Disable annoying source code modification indication (codelenses and text decorations)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know what the correct name is for the issue I am having, or whether it is related to my VSCode, or some of its extensions.

Here is a screenshot depicting the problem:

[image]

Linux, VSCode 1.19.2

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens

Comment: Thank you Alex! You are right. But I still want to remove that 'bracking-lines' string starting with "You, a few seconds ago..."

Answer (score 136, accepted):

```javascript
"gitlens.blame.line.enabled": false,// was working in previous versions
"gitlens.currentLine.enabled": false,// in modern version
"gitlens.codeLens.authors.enabled": false,
"gitlens.codeLens.recentChange.enabled": false,
```

Comment: it was `"gitlens.codeLens.authors.enabled": true,`. Thank you!

Comment: The annoying authors and recent change lenses should be fscking disabled by default. Besides the almost always useless lenses in this case, it pops up an annoyingly huge frame whenever you hover over the lens which makes navigation a huge PITA!

Comment: Now I use Gitlens' Zen Mode command to disable many visual features. The pain subsided.

Comment: Where to add these lines ?

Comment: @vikramvi add these line settings in "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" which you can access via the Command Pallette - `Ctrl + Shift + P`. (`Cmd + Shift + P` for Mac).

Comment: Hey @Alex  Thank you very much for this

Comment: I had to switch off `gitlens.currentLine.enabled`, in UI Settings: Gitlens › Current Line.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me some years of sanity

Comment: needed to disable both `recentChange` and `authors` to get my previous vertical space back. thank you!! 

Answer (score 56):

## Answer for 2019

Ctrl+Shift+P => "Open Settings"
Ctrl+F for "Show the authorship code lenses"
Deselect the line.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, voting this up and any currently above answers down. Took me a while to find this one. Recent things are good things.

Comment: Agree @Jonny, SO needs better mechanisms for this

Comment: now with update become `Current Line Blame`

Answer (score 40):

## June 2023 review:

(GitLens v14.0.1, VSCode v1.79.0)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -> `GitLens: Open Settings`. Then find "Current Line Blame" and "Git Code Lens" headers. Just deselect big checkboxes located at them:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 17):

One can now simply add `"gitlens.mode.active": "zen"` to `settings.json` with Gitlens version `9.5.1` to disable the annoying in-line features.

Tested with VScode `1.31.1` on Windows and Mac.

Comment: So ... how do you get the gitlens features back when you actually want to see them?  I don't see that I can right-click a line and get the git data to display.

Comment: At the bottom right of the VSCode window, there will be a button labeled "Zen".  [Here's a screenshot.](https://imgur.com/a/QOfaMiw)

You can click that and easily disable Gitlens' Zen mode.  When you are done using Gitlens, you can click it again to go back into Zen mode.

Comment: Nice!  So, "Zen" turns to "Reviewing" after I click on "Zen".  Then I click "Reviewing" to go back to zen mode.

Answer (score 4):

The name of the setting that you're looking for is called, **Git Code Lens**.

As mentioned in previous replies, there are several options available in the User or Workspace Settings Configuration. In more recent versions of VS Code, you can more easily access those settings from the menu.

- On Windows/Linux - **File > Preferences > Settings**
- On macOS - **Code > Preferences > Settings**

To update this setting for all projects, Navigate under **User Settings > Extensions > GitLens**. I chose to disable Git Code Lens entirely by deselecting the checkbox for **Code Lens: Enabled**; however, you may only want to disable certain features or only at the workspace level. I have included a screenshot including some of the settings below.

[image]

For additional information on User and Workspace Settings within VS Code: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Answer (score 3):

As of version 8.5.6 you can turn it off with:

```
"gitlens.codeLens.enabled": false
```

Answer (score 3):

## As of 1st Jan, 2022:

Go to settings and search for "current line blame". Then uncheck the option that says *Gitlens>Current Line>Enabled*

Comment: Not enough, it will only disable it for current line.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer for 2022

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` and write `Open Setting` then `Ctrl` + `F` search for `Current Line Blame` turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

2021 recent Visual Code. "Current Line Blame" is the one you should be looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what most people want to achieve. Add these settings to the vscode user preferences:

```json
{
  "gitlens.currentLine.enabled": false,
  "gitlens.codeLens.authors.enabled": false,
  "gitlens.codeLens.recentChange.enabled": false
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10
VSCode 1.63.2
2022 Git> Decorations: Enabled Solves the problem

[Image of vscode settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nhBA.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using GitLens and you are using GitHistoryDiff it has a setting, "Show git blame information for each line". Uncheck that option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turn  off **Inline Blame**, and reactive it when requires.

[image]

-Short code

> Type "Ctrl+Shift+p"

> Find the option "GitLens:open settings"