# Get rid of Code Lens information of VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356510/how-to-disable-codelens-in-vs-code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401967/disable-annoying-source-code-modification-indication), Code Lense from VSCode can be deactivated quite easily.

Now my question:
Where are the author and modify information stored, or how do I get rid of this unnecessary data?

Answer (score 0):

That data is retrieved from your local Git repository or from your source control provider (like TFVC). It's not stored in the project and doesn't take up unnecessary space.