# How do I disable "created 2 hours ago" from code

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS code shows a timestamp when I am editing. Since I don't know what this feature is called, I can't turn it off. [image: image of feature that I don't know how to turn off]

How do I turn this off?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable annoying source code modification indication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401967/disable-annoying-source-code-modification-indication)