# how to disable popup GitHub in vs code

Tags: c#, laravel, git, github

I'm using **`VS Code`** how turn off `GitHub` popup?

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401967/disable-annoying-source-code-modification-indication

Answer (score 3):

if you're using the [GitLens](https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens) extension, just disable the **Hovers** feature in the extension settings.

[image: Gitlens hover disable]

Answer (score 2):

It is mostly due to the extension which you are using in vs code. The extension GitLens gives the details of the commit which were made.

As far as I know, if you click on the git blame line it will show you the pop-up and there isn't any defined way to disable these pop, either way, you can remove the GitLense extension so that the pop-up won't bother you.

Comment: Either you can remove the extension or you can disable it.