# Disable git information in tool tip on current line hover

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have installed a few Git extensions in vscode and one of them is adding git information when I place the cursor on a line of code. Here is the end of it:

[image]

I've disabled Gitlens, restarted and it still shows up.
I've disabled GitHistory, restarted and it still shows up.

I have found a similar question and answer but I have disabled the plugins they describe.

Related:
[Disable annoying source code modification indication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48401967/441016)

...I believe it's GitHistoryDiff.

Answer (score 0):

GitHistoryDiff has a setting, "Show git blame information for each line". Uncheck that option.

If you are not using this extension check GitLens settings mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48401967/441016).

[image]